# Bash inserting extra, incorrect single quotes when quoting argument list

Tags: bash

I'm trying to make a program that will run Maven with certain arguments.

It's basically doing this:

```sh
ARGUMENTS=\""${@:2}"\"
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=$1 -Dexec.args=$ARGUMENTS
```

So running `./myScript.sh a b c` should result in running:

```sh
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=a -Dexec.args="b c"
```

But Maven is throwing errors about an unknown life cycle. Throwing `set -x` in there tells me that the command is actually turning into:

```sh
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=a '-Dexec.args="b' 'c"'
```

Echoing `$ARGUMENTS` gives the expected `"b c"`. What's causing these extra quotes to be added and how can I fix this to get my intended results?

Comment: Bash isn't inserting anything. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 for a full explanation of behavior.

Comment: Slightly less short explanation: Quotes are honored during syntactic parsing, which happens BEFORE expansion, which happens BEFORE string-splitting. Thus, trying to put quotes into place during expansion phase with the hope of modifying string-splitting is doomed to failure. Instead, you want to fix your syntactic quotes, rather than inserting quotes as data.

Comment: ...which is to say: `arguments=${*:2}; java -Dexec.args="$arguments"`.

Comment: Perhaps my prior explanation wasn't quite complete. The reason putting quotes into place during expansion phase is doomed to failure is that if they're put into place during expansion, they aren't there for syntactic parsing, which is the only way they're able to actually determine whether word-splitting and glob expansion take place later.

Comment: It's usually a mistake to hardcode literal quotes, unless you plan to `eval` the command -- and that's almost always a mistake.

Comment: As an aside, implied by the accepted answer: best not to use all-uppercase variable names for _shell-only_ variables so as to avoid potential conflicts with _environment_ variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
arguments="${*:2}"
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="$1" -Dexec.args="$arguments"
```

See [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for a full explanation. That said:

`"$@"` maintains the split between argv array elements -- which is to say that `--foo="$@"`, when `set -- hello world`, resolves to `"--foo=hello" "world"`.

`"$*"` combines argv array elements with the first character of `IFS` between them, which is by default a space.

`$*`, without the double quotes, does the same but fails to prevent string-splitting or glob expansion, thus combining all arguments, but then allowing the shell to split them apart again (and expand globs they contain) -- a behavior which is very rarely desirable.

`arguments="\"${*:2}\""` creates a string -- `"hello world"`. When you run `-Dexec.args=$arguments`, this goes through several phases of processing (excluding ones irrelevant to your current dataset, such as glob expansion):

- Syntactic parsing occurs. It is **at this stage, and only at this stage** when the shell determines which characters are quoted and how. Because no literal quotes exist in `-Dexec.args=$arguments`, the only expansion is recorded as unquoted.
- Expansion occurs. At this point, the expanded string look like `-Dexec.args="hello world"`
- String-splitting occurs. Because the parsing stage already processed, recorded and removed syntactic quotes, any quotes remaining are data, and are processed into individual words. Thus, `-Dexec.args="hello` is a word, and `world"` is a word.

Compare this to the correct usage, `-Dexec.args="$arguments"` (or its effective equivalent, `"-Dexec.args=$arguments"`). At this point:

- Syntactic parsing occurs. This removes the double quotes around `$arguments`, and flags the expansion within as double-quoted.
- Expansion occurs. If you still have literal quotes inside the `arguments` array, they're substituted in as data, making `-Dexec.args="hello world"` the literal data passed to Maven, **including** the quote characters themselves.
- String splitting occurs on expanded strings. In this case, because syntactic parsing flagged the expansion as double-quoted, it has no effect.

If you don't want literal quote characters passed to Maven (and you shouldn't!), simply omit them, and use only syntactic quotes, as done in the example at the top of this answer.

Answer (score 3):

It appears to be quoting issue. Try this with BASH array:

```
arr=( "$@" )
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="$1" -Dexec.args="${arr[*]:1}"
```

Comment: Needs quotes around the `$1`. Also, if all arguments are expected to be concatenated into a single string, the appropriate operator is `*`, not `@`.

Comment: Yes I didn't notice that, added it now. Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. It results in `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=a -Dexec.args=b c`. The arguments are missing their double quotes. I tried adding escaped double quotes around the `"${arr[@]:1}"`, but received the same issue as in the question.

Comment: @Mike, it needs to be `*`, not `@`, for the behavior you want, and you need to quote. (That said, "the behavior you want" is very unfortunate, since it means throwing away data).

Comment: Why would mvn command expect literal quotes? All it needs is `b c` in single argument and that is what this command is doing.

Comment: I'm not sure why Maven would. I get the error `Unknown lifecycle phrase "c"`, which seems to imply that `c` isn't be recognized as part of the argument list.

Comment: In case it matters, this is being run in a subshell, along the lines of `(cd ../../../ && mvn $GOAL $OPTIONS -Dexec.mainClass=$MAINCLASS -Dexec.args="${arr[@]:1}")`. Although I also tried your code verbatim in a new script and received the above mentioned error.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, this worked. Can you please explain (perhaps in an answer of your own) what the difference is?

Comment: To verify the need to use `*` over `@` here: `arr=(foo bar baz); printf "@: %s\n" Dexec.args="${arr[@]:1}"; printf "*: %s\n" Dexec.args="${arr[*]:1}"`

Comment: @glennjackman: Thanks a lot for your edit and comment on explaining difference between `[@]` and `[*]`

Comment: As edited, this is entirely correct; I'm split on whether to maintain my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Followed this cue from the above comments to resolve my issue that the single quotes inserted by bash were causing, when running cucumber tests

> "It's usually a mistake to hardcode literal quotes" by glenn jackman

**What didn't work**
T

```
CUCUMBER_TAGS="\"@happy_path and @disabled\""
mvn verify '-Dcucumber.filter.tags="@happy_path and @disabled"'
```

Bash adds single quotes but `cucumber.filter.tags` doesn't really consume tags in double quotes when inside single quoted mvn properties. I thought it would work as this works in the command line in a non bash script way

`mvn verify -Dcucumber.filter.tags="@happy_path and @disabled"`

**What fixed it**

Not having double quotes in the variable

```
enter code here
CUCUMBER_TAGS="@happy_path and @disabled"
mvn verify '-Dcucumber.filter.tags=@happy_path and @disabled'
```

**Also, for the original question here**
I think this would have worked

```
ARGUMENTS="${@:2}"
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=$1 -Dexec.args=$ARGUMENTS
```

Which would have resulted in this that (works?)

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=a '-Dexec.args=b c'
```